# virtualenv ERROR: the executable in env/bin/python is not functioning

Tags: python, django, macos, pip, virtualenv

### The Problem

I am having great difficulty getting virtualenv to work on my OSX machine. When I run `virtualenv env` I get the error:

```
New python executable in env/bin/python
ERROR: The executable env/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/tylerwendlandt/Documents/Courses/cmput_401' (should be '/Users/tylerwendlandt/Documents/Courses/cmput_401/env')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

I tried looking around for solutions - but I can't seem to get it to work. I don't work with python very often, so this is mostly unfamiliar to me. I attempted to include the needed information, please let me know if more is needed. I appreciate any help - thank you.

### Some info:

**which python**

`/Users/tylerwendlandt/anaconda/envs/ualbertacro/bin/python`

**python --version**

`Python 3.4.3 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.`

**which pip**

`/Users/tylerwendlandt/anaconda/envs/ualbertacro/bin/pip`

**pip --version**

`pip 7.1.2 from /Users/tylerwendlandt/anaconda/envs/ualbertacro/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)`

**which virtualenv**

`/Users/tylerwendlandt/anaconda/envs/ualbertacro/bin/virtualenv`

**virtualenv --version**

`13.1.2`

Comment: I tried `virtualenv env` and `virtual env --python=/Users/tylerwendlandt/anaconda/envs/ualbertacro/bin/python` both resulted in same error

Answer (score 4):

update virtualenv version

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically you are using conda rather than the inbuilt python of mac. So you should do following things:

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
conda install virtualenv
```

Then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 
`virtualenv -p python env`
I think you have path issue, is there something in your PYTHONPATH variable from second error line? If your PYTHONPATH has the first directory in the error line, change it to second one and try again.